# How to sum all deeply nested values in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, sum

I have a hash like:

```
hash = {"0"=>{"0"=>"148", "1"=>"2", "2"=>"90", ....}, "1"=>{"0"=>10}, .....}
```

I want to add all its deeply nested values. What is the best and optimal approach to sum all its values?

I tried it doing this way:

```
hash.values.inject(0){|m,n| m + n.values.map(&:to_i).sum}
```

Comment: Are your hashes guaranteed to have a depth of only 2?

Answer (score 2):

Solving for arbitrary depth is not much different to solving for a fixed depth: a straightforward application of recursion. If the current value is a hash then sum it and add it to the total, if not add the value itself.

```
def hash_sum(h)
  h.values.inject(0) do |total, value|
    case value
    when Hash then total + hash_sum(value)
    else
      total + value.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments and the example, I assume that all relevant values are exactly at depth 2.

```
hash = {"0"=>{"0"=>"148", "1"=>"2", "2"=>"90"}, "1"=>{"0"=>10}}
hash.values.flat_map(&:values).map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
# => 250
```

If you have all the values at depth 3, then add another `flat_map(&:values)`:

```
hash = {"3" => {"0"=>{"0"=>"148", "1"=>"2", "2"=>"90"}, "1"=>{"0"=>10}}, "4" => {"0"=> {"1" => "6"}}}
hash.values.flat_map(&:values).flat_map(&:values).map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
# => 256
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive method that is a variant of Frederick's:

```
def deep_hash(obj)
  return obj.to_i unless obj.is_a? Hash
  obj.reduce(0) { |t,(_,v)| t + deep_hash(v) }
end

hash = { "0"=>{ "0"=>"148, "1"=>"2", "2"=>"90" },
         "1"=>{ "0"=>10, "1"=>{ "0"=>16 } } }

deep_hash(hash)
  #=> 266
```

Answer (score 0):

For max two levels nesting (derived from your solution):

```
hash = {"0"=>{"0"=>"148", "1"=>"2", "2"=>"90"}, "1"=>{"0"=>10}}
hash.values.inject(0) { |m, n| 
  Hash === n ? m + n.values.map(&:to_i).reduce(&:+) : m + n.to_i 
}
#⇒ 250
```

The unlimited nesting solution:

```
def sum_deeply(h)
  h.values.inject(0) { |m, v| 
    m + (Hash === v ? sum_deeply(v) : v.to_i) 
  } 
end
sum_deeply(hash)
#⇒ 250
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is inconsistent. `inject` and `reduce` are aliases of each other. Why use both?

Comment: @sawa Just due to the same reason as why both aliases exist. The first operation is in fact _injecting_ and the latter is _reducing_. I am sure, this is very consistent and I would reject change naming in this case.

Comment: Just to clarify things: there was `reduce` in the second snippet, which was obviously wrong and I changed it. Both `reduce` and `inject` in the first snippet are there on purpose.